# how add svg with use from sprite in java sript

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm stuck with svg sprite placing using use. I would like to add dyanmically svg from sprite using JS and have no idea why it is not working. In my basic HTML where I put one icon inline to HTML icon is displayed but using JS not (use dimensions are 0x0). I suppose there is issue with url during compilation using parcel.

[image: 1]

```
function createSvg(el) {
  const svgElements = ['up2', 'down3'];

  svgElements.forEach(e => {
    const newSvg = document.createElement('svg');
    newSvg.classList.add('country-list__svg');
    el.appendChild(newSvg);
    newSvg.insertAdjacentHTML(
      'afterbegin',
      `<use width="18" height="18" xlink:href="./img/icons.svg#${e}"></use>`
    );
  });
}
```

Thank you in advance for support

I've tried to manipulate width and height attributes but it's not working. I would like to add this svg's and further using CSS change them fill and rotate them on 'click' event.

Comment: before going in your code, you have to be sure svg are loading. In dev tools, net work. In devtools setting you also have a settings to show all xmlhttp requests.

Comment: You need to use  the namespaced `document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg')` for creating svg elements - otherwise these elements are interpreted as HTML DOM elements and won't be rendered.

Comment: I put it to NS and the same. Still use is shown as 0x0 dimensions.
```
      const newSvg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg')
      const use = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
  
      newSvg.classList.add('country-list__svg');
  
      use.setAttributeNS(xlinks, 'xlink:href', `./img/icons.svg#up2`);
      use.setAttribute('width', '18');
      use.setAttribute('height', '18');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code for typos:

The correct namespace value is **"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"** (not "w3.org/2000/svg")

`document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg')`

```js
createSvg(wrap)

function createSvg(el) {
  const svgElements = ['up2', 'down3'];
  const ns ="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

  svgElements.forEach(e => {
    const newSvg = document.createElementNS(ns, 'svg');
    newSvg.classList.add('country-list__svg');
    el.appendChild(newSvg);
    newSvg.insertAdjacentHTML(
      'afterbegin',
      `<use width="18" height="18" xlink:href="#${e}"></use>`
    );
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap"></div>
<!-- hidden svg asset -->
<svg class="icon" style="width:0; height:0; position:absolute;" viewBox="0 0 34 48">
  <path  id="up2" d="M33.16,28.12h-5.2v13h-3.44v-16.72l-7.72-8.72l-7.72,8.72v16.72h-3.44v-13h-5.24l16.4-17.4Z"></path>
</svg>
```

**Alternative: create `<use>`**

```
function createSvg(el) {
  const svgElements = ['up2', 'down3'];
  const ns ="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

  svgElements.forEach(e => {
    const newSvg = document.createElementNS(ns, 'svg');
    const newUse = document.createElementNS(ns, 'use');
    newSvg.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 18 18');
    newUse.setAttribute('width', 18);
    newUse.setAttribute('height', 18);
    newUse.setAttribute('href', `#${e}`);
    newSvg.appendChild(newUse);
    newSvg.classList.add('country-list__svg');
    el.appendChild(newSvg);
  });
}
```

You might not need the deprecated `xlink:href` attribute – unless you need a backwards compatibility for very ancient browsers or a standalone svg that could be edited in graphic applications. `href` is supported by all modern browsers. However, `xlink:href` is still perfectly supported.

If you still can't see any elements: check your **svg file path/URL.**

Make sure your asset svg contains an element with the IDs your referenced. (e.g. "up2" , "down3")